# How efficient is IEnumerable.First and IEnumerable.Last?

Tags: .net, linq, queue, ienumerable, peek

I want to use a System.Collections.Generic.Queue, but with one difference: I want Queue.Peek to return the last item put in rather than the first. I still want items to enter and exit in the same manner.

I was thinking of using Queue.Last() as an alternative to Queue.Peek() (which I assume is basically the same as Queue.First()) But I'm wondering if this means an enumerator will literally enumerator over the entire queue before reaching the last element. Since my queues will be very large, this can be a problem.

EDIT:

To put into perspective what I'm trying to do: Say I want to keep a minute by minute database of the price of a stock for the last 20 years. This would be many data points. In order to do this, I would like to enqueue the lastest price at every minute, and dequeue the earliest price when the size of the queue gets above 20 years. However, I also want a convenient way to get the most recent price from the queue. I know about Queue.Last(), which will do the trick, but I just want to know if it will be terribly inefficient.

Comment: please show what it is you're trying to do in regards to code as it relates to your question..

Comment: It depends on what IEnumerable is pointing at...

Comment: Without any test code with a very large list, sure seems like premature optimization.

Comment: It sounds like you want a deque - there's no deque type in the BCL although you can use `LinkedList<T>` which gives constant-time access to both ends.

Comment: @user3685285 If you are going to need access to arbitrary indices in the collection, then you should use an ICollection type that allows O(1) iterations to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If the collection implements `IList<T>`, then [the indexer property is used](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,75722fd194dc2e0e)** in both `First()` and `Last()` (which is *usually* O(1), though it's not required to be).

**Otherwise, a call to `First()` will only take the first element** (and exit immediately, if the enumerator supports deferred execution), but **a call to `Last()` will have to enumerate the whole collection**.

`IQueue<T>` does not implement `IList<T>`.

Comment: I wish .NET would create a means of extending `IEnumerator<T>` with methods to support expedited skip-ahead and a collection if it knows its count (with auto-generated implementations chaining to static methods for types that don't implement the new methods themselves).  Any implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` could support an `int CountIfKnown` property which was defined as returning -1 for "unknown", and an `int Move(int distance);` property which would perform up to `distance` calls to `MoveNext` and, if `numOk` calls returned successfully, return `distance-numOk`.

Comment: @supercat I think that you can make your own specialized `Last()` for `Queue<T>` that uses reflection to grab a reference to the backing array, a pointer to the first element and the count and jump directly to the last one. It's ugly and you'll be reinventing implementation details of the `Queue<T>` class, but it's probably not impossible. Of course, I too wish LINQ to Objects offered more efficient stuff out of the box for all collections.

Comment: Even if one could implement something like that for `Queue`, how about collection returned from `Append` when given a million-item `List` and an iterator that happens to yield ten items?  Such a type couldn't very well implement `IList<T>`, but could easily implement a parameterized `Move` which could quickly skip over arbitrary numbers of items in the `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't want to use a queue but a deque.

Doing a `Last` call will create an `Enumerator` instance, a private internal class for `Queue<T>` that will be used to enumerate start to end, because [`Queue<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/queue.cs,aa3beab99b2e0db2) does not implement the `IList<T>` interface. Thus `Last` would be an O(n) operation.

Comment: Yes, I was looking at this, but I don't really want to use too many third party stuff, and a deque gives me too much power over my time series.

Answer (score 0):

You're right - for Queues, Last will iterate over every element. Enumerable.Last has a shortcut for ILists, but not for Queues.

It sounds like you just want a queue that remembers the last item added. You could just create a simple wrapper around Queue that can efficiently return the last item...

```
public class StockQueue<T>
{
    private readonly queue; 

    public StockQueue(Queue<T> source)
    {
        this.queue = source;
    }

    public T LastAdded {get; private set;}

    public Enqueue(T item)
    {
        // Remember the last item added
        this.lastAdded = item;
        this.queue.Enqueue(item);
    }

    // Implement any other Queue members you need, passing the calls through
    // to the internal queue.
    public T Dequeue()
    {
        return this.queue.Dequeue();
    }

    public T Peek()
    {
        return this.queue.Peek();
    }
}
```